# win32com + Excel + Django + Apache = problem

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, excel, win32com

I have some problem with opening Excel document in web application
running under Apache(mod_wsgi)/Windows 2008 Server (there is no
problem when the application is running on django developer server -
one thread).

My code:

```
def my_view(request):
   import pythoncom
   from win32com.client import DispatchEx

   pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
   xl = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
   xl.DisplayAlerts = False
   xl.Visible = 0
   doc = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\path\\to\\file.xlsx")
   doc.Saved = True
   ...
   wb.Close(SaveChanges=0)
   xl.Quit()
   pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

Error message:

(-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office Excel',
u"Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file 'C:\path\to
\file.xlsx'. There are several possible reasons: The file name or path
does not exist. The file is being used by another program. The
workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open
workbook.", u'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\
\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)

I know that problem is localized somewhere in threading, but where?
I'm using pythoncom.CoInitializeEx(pythoncom.COINIT_MULTITHREADED).
Maybe changing the server will solve the problem?

Libs: Django 1.2, Apache 2.2 (mod_wsgi), win32com (latest)

I hope somebody can help me.

Thank You,
regards.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of researching the exact same problem I found the solution. It has nothing to do with pythoncom / win32com, but with the fact that the apache is running as a service.
The solution can be found here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91

The solution consists of simply making one folder and giving it write permissions from the relevant (apache) user:

64-bit windows - create this folder:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

32-bit windows - create this folder:

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) module to read Excel files from a (threaded) django project, as Office itself is finicky about not being in the main/GUI thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. I have to manage many macros and do other heavy Excel operations.

Comment: In that case, would a polling solution work? Have a separate process that waits for requests to read Excel files, and processes them in the main (GUI) thread.

Comment: I tried. In that case You have to call this separated process from apache process, and the result is the same ;/

Answer (score 0):

The solution by ichorev didn't work for me.

But I've added application-group=%{GLOBAL} to the WSGIScriptAlias which solved the problem.

Based on this solution [Can't host my wsgi application on other places than /](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/670)

Like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/myuser/Documents/Platform/test-temp/test js playground/webproject/webproject/wsgi.py" application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```